# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: $0 is not defined

Tags: javascript

So I've been working on a loop for something in chrome console.

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: $0 is not defined at win
>   ( 21 :5)

This error is a result of....

```
$0.value = i;
```

what am I doing wrong? I can run that line by itself no problem

Here is the rest of my code....

```
function sleep (ms) {
 return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
}
async function win () {
  if(value >= newvalue){
    i = 2;
    await sleep(1000);
    $0.value = i;
    await sleep(1000);
    push.click()
    await sleep(1000);
    prevalue = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: `$0` is a special variable in the browser console, it's automatically set to the element that you select in the DOM inspector. It's not set automatically in scripts.

Comment: you cannot used $0  in script tag, please read this documentaion from google
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome Developer Tools, `$0` is a special variable that means "the HTML element currently selected for inspection in Chrome Developer Tools".

i.e: select an element (in the Inspect tab) and $0 will be defined.

If no element is selected, then $0 is undefined.

Comment: Being undefined is one thing... being ReferenceError - $0 not defined is another thing.

Comment: Asynchronous functions apparently don't run in the scope that includes this variable, even if they're started from the console. I just tried `setTimeout(function() { console.log($0); }, 100);` and it got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

What is $0 meant to be? If you are trying to use this outside of the console, it will not work.

As the error states `ReferenceError: $0 is not defined` - $0 is NOT defined. 
Any variable needs to be defined before it can be used. So maybe you'd want to do something like:

`var $0 = {};`

But even that would probably not be enough. Given that you're assuming that $0 would be some sort of HTML element, you would need to get that element into $0 yourself and then change values on it.

Comment: no need to get that value in $0, when he will inspect any dom element he will get that value in $0, which is the default behavior